# AlphaAnimation fade out doesn't work any way

Tags: android, android-animation

Animation Alpha fade out doesn't work any way. Fade in, ok works.
But fade out doesn't. What's wrong?

My fade in works fine:

```
Animation anin = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anin.setDuration(1000);
anin.setFillAfter(true);
txtview.startAnimation(anin);
```

My fade out nothing happens :

```
Animation anin = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
anin.setDuration(1000);
anin.setFillAfter(true);
txtview.startAnimation(anin);
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks alright to me, how's the code being used/triggered? Have you also tried a different way of animating the view like this: `txtview.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000)`?

Comment: Hi @Brian. The textview starts with visibility gone (tried starts with invisible too), then I use the fade in to show it, and after a while it should disappear by fade out. The fade in works fine, however fade out doesn't any way. I tried by XML AnimationsUtils... and by view.animate but does not works too.

Comment: When you mean "after a while it should disappear," do you mean it's based on some timer or is there a user interaction that will cause this animation to run? For debugging purposes, maybe try adding an `AnimationListener` just to double check if/how the animation is running.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I don't know what I did but now it works. :)